# Can I fix overwriting text in a plotted model?

Tags: r, graph

I'm making a plot of the Variance decomposition in my VAR model
My Plot looks a bit odd. The text is overwriting in the graph. How do i fix this?

```r
P1FEVD <- fevd(P1modelvar,n.ahead=10)
plot(P1FEVD, main="VD 1986-1999")
```

[image]

Comment: I think you need to go to the extRemes package's documentation and see the methods for plotting `fevd`: `?fevd` should give you some hints. Sorry I can't help more, I haven't used that package

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, this all relies on `barplot`. Hence, you can try a couple of things:

**Overlapping text: Use `oma`**

The overlapping text is actually because the two plots are too close together. You can fix this by providing a larger margin (i.e. a larger white space around the plot). Here, we can fix the problem by adding a wide margin below each plot:

```
plot(P1FEVD, oma = c(3, 0, 0, 0))
```

**Legend fix #1: Use `beside`**

This will place the legend next to the plot. However, it will also extend your x-axis.

```r
plot(P1FEVD, 
     main = "VD 1986-1999", 
     beside = TRUE)
```

**Legend fix #2: Use `args.legend`**

We can provide further arguments towards the legend with `args.legend`. Importantly, we can define the `x` and `y` position in your graph. This may take a few tries to get the `x` position right, but:

```r
plot(P1FEVD, 
     main = "VD 1986-1999",
     args.legend = list(x = nrow(P1FEVD[[1]]) + 3.5, 
                        y = 1))
```